# Custom HTTP method at Mule HTTP point

Tags: http, http-headers, mule

I use Mule as REST API <-> AMQP.
And I have to send custom Request Method: "PRINT", but I'm receiving:

```
Status Code: 400 Bad Request
The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax.
```

Do you have any ideas how I can add custom HTTP method to Mule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, because of this `validateMessage()` method [here](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/7e98da126fa5a2badaa801d0e9011037e04d50d0/transports/http/src/main/java/org/mule/transport/http/HttpMessageProcessTemplate.java#L392) Mule rejects any method not listed [here](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.5.0/transports/http/src/main/java/org/mule/transport/http/HttpConstants.java#L33) :(

I guess you need to open a bug with MuleSoft, asking for the capacity to configure extra methods, and in the meantime create a patch for the transport.